# Is there an easier way to manipulate checkboxes in coldfusion?

Tags: forms, coldfusion, checkbox, cfform

Basically, I have stored information in a database field and I want to display it again through a form.

The original form has the same checkboxes but they are always empty. The user can check the boxes off and the values are put into the database.

Graduate Courses: Fall? Spring? Summer? Stored as a list in a column named grad. (F, M, S)

They have the option to save this lovely form as a draft. When they come back to the draft I need to display what they might have already checked.

```
  <cfif listContains(#grad#, "F") is not 0>
  <input type="checkbox" name="grad" id="grad" value = "F" checked />
  <cfelse>
  <input type="checkbox" name="grad" id="grad" value = "F"  />
  </cfif>
  <cfif listContains(#grad#, "S") is not 0>
  <input name="grad" type="checkbox" id="grad" value = "S" checked />
  <cfelse>
  <input name="grad" type="checkbox" id="grad" value = "S" />
  </cfif>
  <cfif listContains(#grad#, "M") is not 0>
  <input name="grad" type="checkbox" id="grad" value = "M" checked />
  <cfelse>
  <input name="grad" type="checkbox" id="grad" value = "M" />
  </cfif>
```

Is there an easier method to doing this with cfform code?

Just curious. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do it like this, as I don't really use `<cfform>`:

```
<cfloop list="F,S,M" index="g">
  <input type="checkbox" name="grad" id="grad_#g#" value="#g#" #CheckedIf(ListFind(grad, g) gt 0)# />
</cfloop>

<!--- ... --->
<cfscript>
  function CheckedIf(expression) {
    if (arguments.expression) return 'checked="checked"';
    return "";
  }
</cfscript>
```

But the ColdFusion docs state:

> [since] ColdFusion MX: Changed the `cfform` tag
>   `preserveData` attribute behavior: if it
>   is set to `True`, **ColdFusion checks
>   radio and check box values only if
>   their value matches the posted value
>   for the control.**

So yes, `<cfform>` can help you with this. Use `<cfparam name="FORM.xyz" default="foobar">` to emulate the "posted value" for normal requests.

Comment: Mmmm that CheckedIf function just made my day. Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: @Bri: I made a bunch of others in the same spirit (`SelectedIf()`, `DisabledIf()`, `ReadonlyIf()`) that reside in my utility functions library.

Comment: @Tomalak You really helped me out a lot! :) I'm going to start using cfscript more often. I haven't really used it that much, but I feel like it will make my code a lot better. ^^

Comment: @Bri: cfscript has its advantages and dis-advantages. It's nice and short, but it's not type-safe for example, like the more verbose <cffunction> would be. Regarding `preseveData` - I have no idea, really. Try it out. I expect that if you prepare the data in the same way a FORM post would, it can cope with it. See my addition about `<cfparam>`.

Comment: @Bri - To find whole elements, use ListFind/ListFindNoCase not ListContains.

Comment: @Leigh: You are right, `ListContains()` is the wrong function. I'll correct it.